# Using JUnit TemporaryFolder with SpringBoot config property

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4

In my code I get value property like this:

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['myapp.config.path'] ?: T(System).getProperty('java.io.tmpdir')}")
private String path;
```

In test I want set this value using `TemporaryFolder`:

```
@ClassRule
public static TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@BeforeClass
@SneakyThrows
public static void beforeClass() {
    System.setProperty("myapp.config.path", temporaryFolder.newFolder().getAbsolutePath());
}
```

But, when I ran all tests, I have error:

```
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /tmp/systemd-private-eeb0ac8cecc64c6198f53f0516f93d29-systemd-timesyncd.service-UHYtZs
```

How to set a specific property for a particular test and use the default value for the others?

Comment: this error says you don't have permission to `/tmp` folder

Comment: What exactly fails? I guess somewhere in the code you take this path and do something with it. Could you post that code?